# OO - Reduce boilerplate/forwarding code

Tags: oop

Imagine the following: I have a bunch of DTO's that inherit from **Foo class**

```
    class Foo { }

    class FooA : Foo { }

    class FooB : Foo { }

    class FooX : Foo { }
```

Than I have one class that have encapsulated all the related logic and orchestration related with `Foo` data types. I provide a method  `DoSomethingWithData(Foo data)` that do all the logic related to data provided by argument

The method implementation is something like this:

```
void DoSomething(Foo data)
{
     if (data is FooA)
           DoSomethingWithFooA((FooA) data);
     if (data is FooB)
           DoSomethingWithFooB((FooA)data);
     if (data is FooX)
           DoSomethingWithFooC((FooA)data);
}
```

This is a very simplified example. The advantage of this approach is:

- The "Client" invoke always the `DoSomething` method independently of
  the `Foo` data type
- If I add a new type I only have to change the method `DoSomething`

What i dont like is the downcasting

The alternative is instead of exposing only `DoSomething` method I expose a method by each `Foo` data type. The advantage is that we dont have downcast but increases the boilerplate/forwarding code.

What do you prefer? Or do you have other approaches?

Comment: I prefer using C++ and virtual methods, which solve this design pattern properly.

Comment: I think this is mainly about different opinions. You might want to look into "Clean code" by Robert Martin, he has a whole chapter on "data transfer objects" and their pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would approach the problem like this (I will use Java for this example).

In your approach, for every subclass of `Foo` you have to provide a specific processing logic - as you have shown, and cast the `Foo` object to its sub-type. Moreover, for every new class that you add, you have to change the `DoSomething(Foo f)` method.

You can make the `Foo` class an `interface`:

```
public interface Foo{
   public void doSomething();
}
```

Then have your classes implement this interface:

```
public class FooA iplements Foo {
   public void doSomething(){
      //Whatever FooA needs to do.
   }
}

public class FooB implements Foo {
   public void doSomething(){
      //Whatever FooB needs to do.
   }
}
```

And so on. Then, the client can call the `doSomething()` method:

```
...
Foo fooA = new FooA();
Foo fooB = new FooB();

fooA.doSomething();
fooB.doSomething();
...
```

This way, you don't have to cast the object at run-time and if you add more classes, you don't have to change your existing code, except the client that has to call the method of a newly added object.